# Including multiple XSLs into one

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

When working on XML transformation, I would like to combine multiple XSLs so I can reuse code snippets in an easy way.

The following works:
**Gender.xslt**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/person/gender" name="gender">
    <Geslacht>
            <Code>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="genderCode" />
            </Code>
            <Omschrijving>
                <xsl:if test="genderCode=1">Mannelijk</xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="genderCode=2">Vrouwlijk</xsl:if>
            </Omschrijving>
        </Geslacht>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applying to the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" ?>
<person>
    <gender>
        <genderCode>1</genderCode>
    </gender>
</person>
```

I get the following expected outcome

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Geslacht>
    <Code>1</Code>
    <Omschrijving>Mannelijk</Omschrijving>
</Geslacht>
```

In a similar way, I transform an identifier:

**ID.xslt**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/person" name="ssin">
    <INSZ>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ssin" />
    </INSZ>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" ?>
<person>
    <ssin>123456789</ssin>
</person>
```

Gives

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<INSZ>123456789</INSZ>
```

Now I would like to combine the two

Given the following input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" ?>
<person>
    <ssin>1234567891234</ssin>
    <gender>
        <genderCode>1</genderCode>
    </gender>
</person>
```

I would like to obtain the following result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Persoon>
    <INSZ>1234567891234</INSZ>
    <Geslacht>
        <Code>1</Code>
        <Omschrijving>Mannelijk</Omschrijving>
    </Geslacht>
</Persoon>
```

My Stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:include href="Gender.xslt" />
<xsl:include href="ID.xslt" />

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Persoon>
        <xsl:call-template name="gender" />
        <xsl:call-template name="ssin" />
        <xsl:apply-imports />
    </Persoon>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem is that the gender stylesheet gets called, but the result is empty; structure but no data. The SSIN part works like a charm.

Any help is much appreciated!

Barry

Comment: Can you change the structure of the stylesheet modules? In general I would try to rely on template matching and apply-templates instead of combination of applying and calling templates. If the second stylesheet used `<xsl:template match="person/ssin"><INSZ><xsl:apply-templates/></INSZ></xsl:template>`  your life would be easier.

Comment: You could apply everything making a default rule for match="*" doing nothing other than applying further templates. This would be @MartinHonnen s approach too. Alternatively you could change your scope of your template. Currently nothing is happening because your gender template applies specific xpaths inside the gender element. But your current scope is not inside the gender elements. You could use something like <xsl:apply-templates select=".//gender"/> or a <xsl:for-each select=".//gender"/> and call the template inside of it, since for-eaches also change the scope.

Comment: Hello @MartinHonnen. Thanks for your comment. This nearly works, except that INSZ is now around the gender-block as well, something that is undesirable...

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ChristianMosz, pushes me into the right direction (I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to implement the first transformation as

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="gender-descriptions" as="xs:string*"
    select="'Mannelijk', 'Vrouwlijk'"/>

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="person/gender">
      <Geslacht>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </Geslacht>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="gender/genderCode">
      <Code>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </Code>
      <Omschrijving>
          <xsl:value-of select="$gender-descriptions[position() = current()]"/>
      </Omschrijving>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQfG

The second transformation could be implemented as as already indicated in the comment:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="person/ssin">
      <INSZ>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </INSZ>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQfG/1

Then the importing stylesheet would simply do

```
  <xsl:template match="person">
      <Persoon>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </Persoon>
  </xsl:template>
```

(https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQfG/2 has all templates included textually, not imported,  but the result is as you want it).